# Asus A88XM Plus Memory Test

Tags: memory, motherboard, bootrepair

My Asus A88XM Plus based system unexpectedly stopped working and will not now boot. I see the MemOK LED is red and I'd like to try a new stick of memory. Currently the system has a single 8GB Kingston HyperX beast module clocked at 2133MHz. What is a cheap option for me to purchase to try if it is indeed the memory which is at fault? Do I need 2133MHz? 8GB? 4GB? 2GB?

Comment: when I see that led I usually just push the button next to it... I'm not sure what that actually does.

Comment: I saw it and tried it but no luck. It goes through a test sequence indicated by the light flashing at increasing rates. I believe this is only useful for a system which reaches the POST - unlike mine :(

Answer (score 1):

You can download [the manual](http://dlcdnet.asus.com/pub/ASUS/mb/SocketFM2/A88XM-PLUS/E8561_A88XM-PLUS.pdf) from asus.com if you've lost the paper version

Noone other than ASUS can say more than what they have written about what's going to work.  I did notice that they advise extra cooling if you use four SIMMS

> •    For system stability, use a more efficient memory cooling system to support a full 
>   memory load (4 DIMMs) or overclocking condition.

Comment: The link is to the A88XM-E rather than the A88XM Plus. I do still have the paper version. I'm asking about the fact that I don't get to the BIOS menu: if I buy/obtain a smaller DRAM block, say 2GB, and clocked at a lower speed, will it me compatible with my system/BIOS? I don't get that from the manual.

Comment: Thanks for updating the link, that's handy. My system has just one 8GB stick. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

A88XM Plus supports several kinds memory of DDR3, like dual channel DDR3 2400MHz (overclocking) , 2250MHz (overclocking) , 2200MHz (overclocking) , 2133MHz ,1866MHz , 1600MHz and 1333MHz, so we can select one memory (2133MHz or 1866MHz or 1600MHz or 1333MHz) with at least 4G, its price we can select depend on our economic situation and our requirement, it seems the smaller the memory size, the cheaper the price.

Comment: How do you know that it should be above 4GB?

Comment: Windows 10 just uses 2GB RAM, The computer uses about 50% RAM with nothing in the foreground. So it needs at least 4G memory.

Comment: A 2GB module worked. I run 64-bit Ubuntu. This tells me it was indeed the RAM at fault. I'll now order more to repair my system.